# How to retrieve deleted records using vb.net and vfpoledb provider

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve deleted records in a DBF (dBase IV).

For now I'm using this connection string:

```
Constring = " Provider = vfpoledb; Data Source=" & path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV DELETED=true"
```

Works fine but can't retrieve the deleted records.

Comment: Have the deleted records been transferred to an inactive table? If not maybe logs can be accessed or a back up of the database.

Comment: I'm afraid sir but there is no log for deleted record and i just cannot create log or database of deleted records for some reason

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Constring = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""dBase IV;DELETED=true"""`, i.e. with the extended properties value in double quotes?

Comment: Been a while since I've had to do much with vfp data, but I've got this nagging feeling that even though dBase IV and vfp share much of the same structure, there where a couple anomalies when mixing the two

Comment: Hi Andrew i tried this nothing happened

Comment: hi Hursey, should i change my provider? if yes what provider should i use?

Comment: @DaveLabartine In [this thread on vbforums.com](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?42976-VB6-amp-dBase-IV-files-How-to-show-deleted-records&s=459d4528b62c63297872e77aee0f5bfc&p=179277&viewfull=1#post179277) I see someone suggesting using "Deleted=No;" to be able to retrieve the deleted records.